# How to change order key and value array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to change order of the key and value in an array to specified order in javascript

From this

```
{  
   [
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "John",
   "address" : "Britain"
   ]
}
```

to this

```
{  
   [
   "id" : 1,
   "address" : "Britain",
   "name" : "John",
   ]
}
```

I have research the solution but not any work

Comment: Please include valid JavaScript.

Comment: the data's is from database i want the response look like that, i want to add one response and put the new response in spesified position.


```
for(dt let of data){
   dt.new_response = (logic)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To define object you need **{ }** in array.
for your problem, try this instead :

```
const arr = [{"id" : 1,  "name": "John", "address": "Britain" }]

const sortOrder = {'id': 1, 'address': 2, 'name': 3}

const res = arr.map(o => Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(o).sort((a, b) => sortOrder[a] - sortOrder[b]).map(x => { return { [x]: o[x]}})))

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic method here is to copy the properties in the order you want them to a new object. For simple objects, this should suffice:

```
let x = {  
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "John",
   "address" : "Britain"
};

const reorderObject = function(source, ...keyList)
{
    let result = [];

    // Ensure the list of keys are only those present in the source object

    let sourceKeyList = Object.keys(source);
    keyList = keyList.filter(i => sourceKeyList.includes(i));
    
    // Copy the properties you want in the order you want them to a new object
    
    keyList.forEach(i => result[i] = source[i]);
    
    // Copy any remaining properties
    
    sourceKeyList.filter(i => !keyList.includes(i)).forEach(i => result[i] = source[i]);

    return(result);
}

// USAGE:

console.log(reorderObject(x, "id", "address", "name"));
```